# Creatorbot-3D Kickstarter assembly instructions

Tags: diy-3d-printer, 3d-printerworks

I disassembled my printer a couple of years ago for a move and now I'm getting back to it and can't find the manual detailing the assembly anywhere and the google drive link is gone. Does anyone have a copy of the PDF somewhere?

Comment: Being curious - what is your main concern? The order of doing things? The mechanical part, screwing, etc.? Or electronics andb cabling?

Answer (score 2):

In the comments for the [Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/920076234/the-creatorbot-3d-printer-professional-grade-large/comments), there is a Google Drive link that is still active [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c_LtrJrt6LFdcwhY34014x-TkXsHUBMM/view).